# Fourier series for a Sinusoid in a conventional way?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, fourier-series, signal-processing

So my TA in class introduced this amazing way of finding fourier series coefficients for a sin wave, by writing

$ sin( \omega t ) = (e^{i\omega t}-e^{-i\omega t}) / 2i $ ----(1)

Hence getting the form of the desired fourier coefficients.

Then I thought of substituting the same in the common formula given for fourier series

$x(t) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}C_k e^{ik\omega _o t}, \omega_o=2\pi/(period)$ ----(2)

$C_n=\frac{1}{T} \int_T x(t)e^{-in\omega_o t}dt $  ----(3)

Putting RHS of (1) in (3)

$ \frac{\omega}{2\pi} \int _0^{2\pi} (e^{i\omega t}-e^{-i\omega t})e^{-in\omega t}dt  $

Taking $f=i \omega t$ therefore $dt=\frac{df}{i\omega}$, Hence the equation becomes

$\frac{-1}{4\pi}\int_0^{i2\pi\omega} (e^f-e^{-f}) e^{-nf} df$

$\frac{-1}{4\pi}\int_0^{i2\pi\omega} (e^{f(1-n)}-e^{-f(1+n)})df$

Solving this gives and using that $e^{i2\pi}=1$ we get

$\frac{-1}{4\pi} [ \frac{1^{\omega (1-n)} -1}{1-n} + \frac{1^{\omega (1+n)} -1}{1+n} ]  $

This conveniently gives 0 for all values except for n=-1 and n=1. How to evaluate this to match it with the coefficients of equation (1). I am also unable to calculate the limit, which I was getting as 0.

Comment: Your final expression is only valid if $n$ is not equal to $1$ or $-1$. If $n$ has one of those values, then the corresponding exponential term in the integral will simply be $1$. For example, if $n=1$, then the integral (second to last expression) becomes $$\int (1 - e^{-f(1+n)})df$$

Comment: But is going to the last step from the second last step wrong for n=1 and n=-1 ?

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect. The integral formula $$\int e^{ax}dx = \frac{1}{a}e^{ax}$$ is only true if $a \neq 0$. You have to handle the cases $n=1$ and $n=-1$ separately.